# How to create a figure with subplots for each category in a pandas column

Tags: python, pandas, seaborn, subplot, displot

I have a pandas df which I would like to plot in a displot with seaborn. I have a variable to plot, A, and a variable to hue, B. The problem is that the B variable has ca. 50 different values, so I would like to automatically create a grid of each subplots, say 5 columns and the neccessary number of rows.

Right now I can only put the plots in row or columns, with:

```
sns.displot(data=df, x="A", col="B")
```

or

```
sns.displot(data=df, x="A", row="B")
```

Is there a way to achieve the desired result?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Are you looking for [`col_wrap`](https://seaborn.pydata.org/generated/seaborn.displot.html) ?

> `col_wrap` : *int*
> **Wrap the column** variable at this width, **so that the
> column facets span multiple rows**..

```
g = sns.displot(data=df, x="A", col="B", hue="B", col_wrap=5, height=3, aspect=1)

g.fig.tight_layout()

plt.show();
```

Output :

[image]

*Input used :*

```
from string import ascii_uppercase

np.random.seed(1)

df = pd.DataFrame({
    "A": np.random.randn(1000),
    "B": np.random.choice([*list(ascii_uppercase[-10:])], 1000)
})
```

Comment: @datadatadata In general, double encoding a parameter is not a good practice. There is no reason to use hue, since each plot is already titled with the parameter.

Answer (score 0):

- With `df` from this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/76372928/7758804), this can be accomplished using [`pandas.DataFrame.plot`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.plot.html), and [`kind='hist'`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.hist.html), without the need to import another package.

  - `pandas.DataFrame.plot` uses `matplotlib` as the default backend, and `seaborn` is a high-level API for `matplotlib`.
- There's no reason for each subplot to be a different color.

  - [Avoid Unnecessary Usage of Color](https://chartio.com/learn/charts/how-to-choose-colors-data-visualization/#avoid-unnecessary-usage-of-color)
  - From [*Practical Rules for Using Color in Charts by Stephen Few, Perceptual Edge*](https://www.perceptualedge.com/articles/visual_business_intelligence/rules_for_using_color.pdf), in the **Use Color Meaningfully and with Restraint** section: color usage in this plot means nothing, and should be avoided.

```py
# plot the dataframe
ax = df.plot(kind='hist', by='B', bins=20, layout=(2, 5), figsize=(15, 6), legend=False, ec='k', sharey=True, sharex=True)
```

[image]